# Creating a simple web using the pokemon tcg api

Tags: javascript, api, local-variables, createelement

We are trying to make a selection of options based on the pokemon different card generations with their value being the image of that generation of the card, then we want an event listener to check for a  click us that takes the value and changes the photo.

The problem I am running into is I'm trying to access the local var of options that's nested in my conditional and I can't seem to figure out how to access it so I can make the event listener work the way I intend it to.

**Code:**

```js
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', getPokemon)

const img = document.querySelector('#img')
const sel = document.querySelector('#curPoke')

function getPokemon(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const poke = document.querySelector('#input').value.toLowerCase();
    const url = `https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards`;

    fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.data.forEach(card => {
                if (poke === card.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    let option = document.createElement('option')

                    option.textContent = `${card.name} ${card.id}`

                    option.value = card.images.large;
                    option.classList.add('gen')
                    sel.append(option)
                    sel.classList.remove('hide')

                    img.src = option.value
                }
                console.log(img.src)
            })
            console.log(data)
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

document.querySelector('option').addEventListener('click', function() {
    img.src = option.value
})

sel.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // img.src = option.value
    console.log('click')
    const opt = document.querySelector('.gen')
    console.log(opt)
})
```

Comment: Do you have any exception in the console? If so, can you put it in your question?

Comment: no, I was just logging that so I can get a visual cue on what my app is doing to ensure it's working the way I want to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
option.addEventListener('click', function(){
    img.src = option.value;
});
```

Into the conditional like this:

```
fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            data.data.forEach(card => {
                if (poke.toLowerCase() === card.name.toLowerCase()) {
                    let option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.textContent = `${card.name} ${card.id}`;
                    option.value = card.images.large;
                    option.classList.add('gen');
                    sel.append(option);
                    sel.classList.remove('hide');
                    img.src = option.value;

                    option.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        img.src = option.value;
                        console.log(img.src);
                    });
                }
               
            });
            console.log(data);
        }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Also notice the `poke.toLowerCase() === card.name.toLowerCase()` condition. This way you will prevent case where no pokemon is found, if user will put name with capital letters.

Comment: ok lemme try this I tried a version of this and it didn't seem to work maybe I was missing something but thank you so much.

Comment: ok so I Attempted that and the problem is for a reason when all the options are made it only reads the first option even though when slicking on the other card generations, and when outside the function it doesn't seem to work properly is there any way to grab that local const option varible i made outside of that conditional ?

Comment: I fixed code in answer there should be `option.addEventListener` not `document.querySelector('option').addEventListener` now it should work, but event triggered by clicking 'sel' element also will be triggered

Comment: yeah I also tried that as well but it didn't seem to work I'm going to try hitting the drawing board again, the option event listener only returns the first option I created and not the others, thank you so much for the response so far.

Comment: I created a working codepen example for you also with some html elements, here is the link:
https://codepen.io/Tensoniusz/pen/KKNvWqB?editors=1111

Comment: Thank you I will check it out now and let you know an update!